# XmlService error getting nested child element (Google AppScript)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, xml-parsing

Looking for assistance with an error I'm getting when attempting to get a nested node value in an XML file using XmlService and Google's AppScript. The node name is "asciiformat" and its position in the XML file is according to below (this is a simplified version; find full XML structure below AppScript code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
    <entry>
        <tes:ftpjob xmlns:tes="http://www.software.com">
            <tes:asciiformat>N</tes:asciiformat>
```

Here's the error from AppScript:

```
TypeError: ftpJobInfo.getChildren is not a function
doGet   @ Code.gs:17
```

Here's the code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  let fileID = '1qHbA97eVaJtPWU3g_f9dEtwg-rlvkpc2';
  url = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob().getDataAsString();  
  let document = XmlService.parse(url);

  let root = document.getRootElement();

  let ns = root.getNamespace();
  let entries = root.getChildren("entry", ns);
  let entry, ftpJobInfo, ftpJobInfoDetails;

  let id, title, asciiFormat;
  for (let counter = 0; counter < entries.length; counter++) {
    entry = entries[counter];
 
    ftpJobInfo = entry.getContent(8);
    ftpJobInfoDetails = ftpJobInfo.getChildren('tes:ftpjob');
    
    asciiFormat = ftpJobInfoDetails.getContent(0).getValue();

    Logger.log("prayer hands");
  }
}
```

Here's the full XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
    <title>tes-6.5/tes:FTPJob.getList</title>
    <category term="0" scheme="row" label=""/>
    <category term="0" scheme="level" label=""/>
    <category term="111111111111111111111111" scheme="securitypolicy" label=""/>
    <category term="000000000000000000000000" scheme="customsecuritypolicy" label=""/>
    <generator uri="http://www.software.com">TES</generator>
    <modified>2022-08-04T15:41:11.027-06:00</modified>
    <entry>
        <id>9966</id>
        <title>01 PMI SFTP</title>
        <category term="0" scheme="row" label=""/>
        <category term="0" scheme="level" label=""/>
        <category term="111111111111111111111111" scheme="securitypolicy" label=""/>
        <category term="000000000000000000000000" scheme="customsecuritypolicy" label=""/>
        <source>com.software.FTPJobView</source>
        <tes:ftpjob xmlns:tes="http://www.software.com">
            <tes:asciiformat>N</tes:asciiformat>
            <tes:ftphost>1.1.1.1:722</tes:ftphost>
            <tes:filename>*.txt</tes:filename>
            <tes:ftpoperation>2</tes:ftpoperation>
            <tes:ftpprotocol>sftp</tes:ftpprotocol>
            <tes:ftpuserid>25</tes:ftpuserid>
            <tes:localpath>\\localpath</tes:localpath>
            <tes:newfilename/>
            <tes:replacefiles>N</tes:replacefiles>
            <tes:userpasswordauthentication>Y</tes:userpasswordauthentication>
            <tes:id>9966</tes:id><tes:typename>FTPJOB</tes:typename>
            <tes:name>01 PMI SFTP</tes:name><tes:parentname>\location\location\location</tes:parentname>
            <tes:active>Y</tes:active>
            <tes:ownerid>16</tes:ownerid>
            <tes:agentid>65</tes:agentid>
            <tes:command>\\location</tes:command>
            <tes:createtime>2012-08-08T11:05:27-0600</tes:createtime>
            <tes:dependencylogic>1</tes:dependencylogic>
            <tes:fullpath>\location\location\location</tes:fullpath>
            <tes:lastchangetime>2019-07-19T17:27:42-0600</tes:lastchangetime>
            <tes:runuserid>25</tes:runuserid>
        </tes:ftpjob>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, the structure of XML data has already been known. When this situation is used, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
let document = XmlService.parse(url);

let root = document.getRootElement();

let ns = root.getNamespace();
let entries = root.getChildren("entry", ns);
let entry, ftpJobInfo, ftpJobInfoDetails;

let id, title, asciiFormat;
for (let counter = 0; counter < entries.length; counter++) {
  entry = entries[counter];

  ftpJobInfo = entry.getContent(8);
  ftpJobInfoDetails = ftpJobInfo.getChildren('tes:ftpjob');
  
  asciiFormat = ftpJobInfoDetails.getContent(0).getValue();

  Logger.log("prayer hands");
}
```

##### To:

```
const search = "asciiformat"; // This is from your question.
const root = XmlService.parse(url).getRootElement();
const ns = XmlService.getNamespace("tes", "http://www.software.com");
const value = root.getChild("entry", root.getNamespace()).getChild("ftpjob", ns).getChild(search, ns).getValue();
console.log(value) // N is returned.
```

- When `url` is your showing XML data, when you run this modified script, you can see the value of `N` in the log.

#### Note:

- In your showing script, I think that `ftpJobInfo = entry.getContent(8);` has no value. By this, I think that this might be the reason for your issue. And, from your showing XML data, the tag of `entry` is only one. So, in this case, I thought that `getChildren` is not required to be used. And, from your XML data, it seems that the namespace of `ftpjob` is `tes`. This can be used for retrieving the tag of `asciiformat`. So, I proposed the above modification.
- As another direction, when [this benchmark](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/07/14/benchmark-process-cost-for-parsing-xml-data-using-google-apps-script/) is considered, I thought that the following sample script might be able to be also used.

  ```
    const res = url.match(/<tes:asciiformat>(.+)<\/tes:asciiformat>/);
    console.log(res && res[1]); // N is returned.
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getChild(name, namespace)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getChild(String,Namespace))

Answer (score 1):

This function will return the value of any node in an XML file by looping through all elements and attempting to match the name.  It's returning the `getValue()` parameter (which would be better if it was an input variable, but I hard coded it to match your request).

**Small update to account for if using prefix. Should work either way if nameToFind has colon or not.**

```
function getElementValue() {
  const nameToFind = "tes:asciiformat";
  const fileID = '1qHbA97eVaJtPWU3g_f9dEtwg-rlvkpc2';
  const url = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob().getDataAsString();

  var zElements = XmlService.parse(url).getRootElement()
    .getDescendants().map(x => x.asElement()).filter(y => y != null);

  zElements.forEach(function (x, zIndex) {
    var zCheckName = ((nameToFind.search(":") >= 0) ? x.getNamespace()
      .getPrefix() + ":" : '') + zElements[zIndex].getName();
    if (zCheckName == nameToFind) {
      var zOutput = zElements[zIndex].getValue()
      Logger.log(zOutput);
      return zOutput;
    }
  })
}
```